# Update freetype version for PHP on amazon linux 2

Tags: linux, php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to update freetype on amazon elastic beanstalk php but not sure of the full process. It comes with freetype 2.3.11 which is quite old and is causing problems with my application. I have added a file in .ebextensions which does install an upgraded freetype version but php is still using the old version. Does php need recompiled or reinstalled to update the version of freetype?

```
commands:
    01_freetype_install:
        cwd: /tmp
        command: |
            wget https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.6.5.tar.bz2 \
            && tar -xjf freetype-2.6.5.tar.bz2 \
            && cd freetype-2.6.5 \
            && sed -ri "s:.*(AUX_MODULES.*valid):\1:" modules.cfg \
            && sed -r "s:.*(#.*SUBPIXEL_RENDERING) .*:\1:" -i include/freetype/config/ftoption.h \
            && ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static \
            && make \
            && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The modules need to be compiled along with the interpreter. The only (possible) exception *may* be when the version change is very small, and the changes did not affect the module you are attempting to add.

HTH